# Hashbang priority vs clean url

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

Hi I am a newbie in google analytics.I have implemented a site with angularjs and Rails.Because of the use of angularjs the url generated is with hashbang(#!)
for eg:-www.abc.com/#!/xyz

Now I have made the website crawlable by google with the help of escaped fragment.So the website is crawlable and the results are shown in google.

Now the SEO professionals in our office is telling me that a cleaner url ie without hashbang (www.abc.com/xyz) has more priority in results.

All I want to ask is,is this true and will it not create duplicate pages if implemented.

Comment: You may find [this](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/) very useful on the subject...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the URL alone does not affect ranking in any visible way.

That said, if you're creating a new site, I'd recommend using HTML5 pushState/replaceState instead: serve a fully rendered page on first load, use the history API to navigate within the site. AJAX-crawling is still supported (at least by Google), but there are cleaner alternatives nowadays.